# Meshes not showing up correctly in Blender when opening a blender file

Tags: mesh, blend-files

I seem to be running into some trouble while using Blender. Whenever I try to open a blender file in my latest version of Blender, none of the meshes in the said file show up. I can see thin lines in wireframe view, I can't see any meshes in solid or material views, and I can see a transparent version of the meshes themselves in rendered view. Maybe there's a bug with this program. But regardless, I need some help finding a solution to this problem I'm currently having.

Comment: Hello and welcome. can you attach your blend file. https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: An image of the effect you're seeing would help but it sounds like a graphics driver problem. Have you updated the graphics card drivers recently?

Comment: I might have found a solution myself. All I had to do was disable GPU Subdivisions.